# Visibility and Atmospheric Pressure

Tags: planets, atmosphere

How closely is a world's atmospheric opacity related to its atmospheric pressure? I know there are *many* things that will reduce visibility, like fog and smoke, but on average, how much would visibility decrease with pressure?

EDIT: I should probably mention that I'm really bad at mathematics.
What I want to know *in particular* is how poor visibility would be (in simplified circumstances) with an atmospheric density of 4.432  kg/m³ and a star with stellar luminosity of 1.59 (radius 1.21*sun, temperature 5872K).

Comment: This might be a better question for the Physics or maybe Earth Science stacks rather than Worldbuilding, seeing as how this isn't really about or related to WB. Air is compressible, so assuming higher pressure at the same temperature, density will be higher. There'll be more particles per volume to help scatter and attenuate light, so opacity definitely goes up. Can't say "how much" without looking around for the right equations.

Answer (score 6):

For ideal gasses, optical depth is directly proportional to density, and thus to pressure, and attenuation per unit distance (and thus visibility) is exponentially related to optical depth. The base of the exponent depends on the specific absorption/scattering characteristics of the gas, and is also dependent on wavelength, so there is no single numerical answer to how much visibility changes with pressure; in general, you want the [Beer-Lambert Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law).

Comment: IIRC perceived brightness is a logarithm of actual intensity, so while there's a constant, for a given wavelength and gas mixture, I think this implies a linear inverse relationship between the amount of gas/pressure and perceived brightness!

Comment: Thanks for this information!

Comment: Thank-you! I should probably have mentioned that I'm nowhere near an expert in mathematics, though. To my credit, I /have tried/ to understand the formulas shown in that link. I'll update my question and try to move it somewhere more appropriate.